# Null Pointers & Object Pointers

Tags: c++

I was given instructions to show that a pointer variable can contain a pointer to a valid object, deleted object, null, or a random value. Set four pointer variables a,b,c, and d to show these possibilities. The the thing im not sure about are the pointer objects. Can someone explain what I need to do to show case these pointers.  or if I did it right.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

class Pointer
 {
 public:
 Pointer()
{
    int num = 2;
}
Pointer(int num)
{
    this->numb = num;
}
void set(int num)
{
    numb = num;
}
int Get()
{
    return numb;
}

 private:
int numb;



};
int main ()
{

Pointer point;
Pointer* a;
a = &point;
Pointer*b = new Pointer(10);
delete b;
int* c = NULL;
srand(unsigned(time(0)));
int randNum = rand()%100;
int *d;
d = &randNum;

cout <<"Pointer a: " << a << endl;
cout <<"Pointer b: " << b << endl;
cout <<"Pointer c: " << c << endl;
cout <<"Pointer d: " << *d << endl;
//(*a) = (*b);

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, because this is homework, but here’s a hint: once you generate random bits (The C++ STL way to do this is with `<random>` and perhaps `<chrono>`), you can store them in a `uintptr_t`, an unsigned integer the same size as a pointer, and convert those bits to a pointer with `reinterpret_cast<void*>(random_bits)`.  The results are undefined behavior.  Trying to dereference the pointer *might* crash the program, or it might *appear* to work and corrupt some other memory location, or it might do different things on different runs of the program, but nothing you do with it is guaranteed to work predictably.  This is Very Bad.

If “random” really means arbitrary, for this assignment, you could just declare a pointer off the stack (that is, inside a function and not `static`) and not initialize it. Ask your instructor if you aren’t sure.

That’s a very common source of irreproducible bugs, and I would recommend you get into the habit now of *always* initializing your pointer variables when you declare them.  Often, that lets you declare them `int * const`, which is good practice, but even if you need to wait to assign a real value to them, if you initialize your pointers to `NULL` or `nullptr`, you will always see immediately in the debugger that the value is uninitialized, and you will always crash the program if you try to use it uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to first point out what the word NULL means or nullptr, which is what you should be using in C++11. The null pointer just assigns the pointer to an inaccessible address or location in the memory. This allows for safer code, because the "dangling pointers" left over could be bad.

A header file and another cpp file to define the class

```
Class Something{

     // Class implementation here
};
```

Now lets go to the main.cpp file

```
#include "The header you made.hpp" // (.h or .hpp)    

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
     Something objOne;
     Something *objPointer = &objOne;
        // Do stuff with objPointer
             // Like use your member functions
     Something *objPointerTwo = &objOne;
             // Now objPointerTwo points to the same object

     // Lets try some runtime allocation of memory

            Something *objHeap = new Something();
                     // Do something with the pointer
                   // Watch this
           delete objHeap;
           objHeap = nulltpr;
     // Now what happens when you try to access methods again with objHeap 
            // Your program will display a segmentation fault error
            // Which means you are trying to mess with memory
            // that the compiler does not want you too


  }
```

All right so what is this memory? Well to put it simply you have the heap and the stack. All the stuff you put into your program is put into the stack when it is compiled. So when the program runs the code follows main and traces the stack kind of like a stack of boxes. You may get need to search through all the top ones to get to the bottom. Now what if a person didn't know for example how many students were going to be in the class that year. Well the program is already running how do you make more room? This is where the heap comes in. The new keyword allows you to allocate memory at runtime, and you can "point" to memory on the "heap" if you will. Now while this is all good and cool, it can be potentially dangerous which is why people consider C++ and C dangerous languages. When you are done using that memory on the heap you have to "delete" it so when the pointer moves, the memory does not get lost and cause problems. It is kind of like a sneaky ninja and it goes and causes trouble.

A good way to think about how pointers can be good for objects is if you create say a deck class, well how many cards does the user want we wont know until runtime, so lets have them type in the number, and we can allocate it on the heap! Look Below

```
int main(void){
 int count;
 Deck *deck = nullptr;
 std::cout << "Enter amount of cards please:";
 std::cin >> count;
 deck = new Deck(count); // RUNTIME ALLOCATION ON HEAP!!!!
      // This is so cool right, you can have a deck of any size
  // Do stuff with deck


  // Now that we are done with the deck don't forget to delete it 
  // We do not need all those cards on the heap anymore so....
         delete deck; // Ahhh almost done
         deck = nullptr; // Just in case since dangling pointers are weird

}
```

The key thing to understand here is, what is a pointer, what is it pointing to, and how do they work with the memory!